# Basic Makefile to create .expected files

Tags: beginner, makefile

I wrote a simple Makefile to build `.expected` files and compare them. It works as expected and I was wondering it would be great if I could get some feedback. More specifically if I followed all conventions and if it can be improved upon. This is my first Makefile.

```
# Relative path
RELATIVE_PATH=..
APSSCHED=$(RELATIVE_PATH)/bin/apssched
EXAMPLES=$(RELATIVE_PATH)/examples
BASE=.:$(RELATIVE_PATH)/base:$(EXAMPLES)
FLAGS=-DCOT
CASES=simple-binding1 simple-binding2 simple-binding3

# Generate output and store it in a file
%.output: $(EXAMPLES)/%.aps
    $(APSSCHED) $(FLAGS) -p $(BASE) $(basename $<) > $@

# Copy actual output as expected
%.expected: %.output
    cp -f $< $@

# Compare actual output with expected
.PHONY: %.compare
%.compare: %.output
# maybe there is a better way without using basename ...
    diff $(basename $@).expected $<

# Generate and verify all outputs
.PHONY: all
all: $(addsuffix .compare,$(CASES))

# Regenerate expected output
.PHONY: build.expected
build.expected: $(addsuffix .expected,$(CASES))

.PHONY: clean.expected
clean.expected:
    -rm -f *.expected
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE.